# Exception thrown when connecting Neo4j+HA and Spring Data- "Missing Mandatory Setting ha.initial_hosts"

Tags: neo4j, high-availability, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to create a sample node in Neo4j Graph DB but getting an exception when starting tomcat. I am using Neo4j+HA+Spring Data Graph Repository to create a node. 
I am sure there is something wrong on how I configured. I am getting below exception.
All my 3 neo4j clusters are configured and started.I used exact configuration as specified in the link [Neo4j HA Conf Tutorial](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/ha-setup-tutorial.html)

Let me know if you want me to paste any of other code/classes.

I see below exception.

```
    Could not instantiate bean class [org.neo4j.kernel.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase]: 
Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Missing mandatory setting 'ha.initial_hosts'
```

Below is the complete exception.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.estimates.topack.services.PersonService com.estimates.topack.HomeController.personServices; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personService': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'neo4jTemplate' while setting bean property 'neo4jTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.data.neo4j.aspects.config.Neo4jAspectConfiguration#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'haDatabase' while setting bean property 'graphDatabaseService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'haDatabase' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.neo4j.kernel.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing mandatory setting 'ha.initial_hosts'
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913) ~[spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464) ~[spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385) ~[spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284) ~[spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111) [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303) [na:1.6.0_51]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) [na:1.6.0_51]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [na:1.6.0_51]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [na:1.6.0_51]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [na:1.6.0_51]
```

Web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml


            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

my ApplicationContext.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 

    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd

      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:spring-configured />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.estimates.topack" />
    <neo4j:repositories base-package="com.estimates.topack.services" />

 <bean id="haDatabase" class="org.neo4j.kernel.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase"
           destroy-method="shutdown">
       <constructor-arg index="0" value="data/graph.db"/>
       <constructor-arg index="1">
           <map>
               <entry key="ha.server_id" value="1"/>
               <entry key="ha.server" value="127.0.0.1:6363"/>
               <entry key="ha.coordinators" value="127.0.0.1:5001,127.0.0.1:5002,127.0.0.1:5003"/>
           </map>
       </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
<neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="haDatabase" />
    </beans>
```

***Latest Exception I get:***

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.estimates.topack.services.PersonService com.estimates.topack.HomeController.personServices; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personService': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'neo4jTemplate' while setting bean property 'neo4jTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.data.neo4j.aspects.config.Neo4jAspectConfiguration#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'graphDatabaseService' while setting bean property 'graphDatabaseService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'graphDatabaseService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.neo4j.kernel.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.ha.BranchedDataMigrator@2738ef1d' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913) ~[spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464) ~[spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385) ~[spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284) ~[spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111) [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303) [na:1.6.0_51]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) [na:1.6.0_51]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [na:1.6.0_51]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [na:1.6.0_51]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [na:1.6.0_51]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The config of bean `haDatabase` is incomplete. Neo4j 1.9.x does not use `ha.coordindator`, use `ha.initial_hosts` instead. `ha.coordinator` was used up to 1.8.x.

Comment: Okay...I will try that and will accept your answere. Thank you

Comment: I have one more error coming up...can you please take a quick look

Comment: this is the error i get java.io.InvalidClassException: org.neo4j.cluster.member.paxos.MemberIsAvailable; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 977671511575679253, local class serialVersionUID = -2826926850135965485

Comment: And also getting this error.  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'graphDatabaseService' is defined
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]

Comment: which version of Neo4j are you using?

Comment: I am using version 1.9.2

Comment: I asked same question here...please update you answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17774703/exception-thrown-when-connecting-neo4jha-and-spring-data-no-bean-named-graphd

Comment: I modified by applicationContext.xml and now i get following error Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.ha.HaXaDataSourceManager@3ae86a5f' was successfully initialized, but failed to start

Comment: Can you please suggest a solution for this please? I am actually stuck here and unable to create a my sample node

Comment: what's the full stacktrace of the exception you're seeing? Also did you recently upgrade from a previous version?

Comment: I have update full stacktrace in my original question above under "Latest Exception I get:". I downloaded 2.0.0 first but I could not configure it for HA. So downloaded 1.9.2 into 3 different folder and Configured it for HA. I was able to start all 3 servers.

Comment: I have same question asked in the following link. It has my latest applicationContext.xml update as well. Just in case you want to see it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17774703/exception-thrown-when-connecting-neo4jha-and-spring-data-org-neo4j-kernel-ha-br

Comment: Since you've played back and forth with different versions, try to shut down the whole cluster, get rid of data/graph.db (deleting you db contents) and start fresh with an empty db and see if the issue persists.

Comment: Thank you,I currently don't have the PC in which i was trying Neo4j. I will try and will let you know.

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. I am getting the same exception.

Comment: any other suggestion please?

Comment: Do you have the underlying exception stracktrace from the " Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.ha.BranchedDataMigrator@2738ef1d' was successfully initialized, but failed to start."? maybe you need to tweak your application's log settings.